# Finiteness of rational points on certain open subset of surfaces of general type

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, diophantine-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth surface of general type defined over a number field $k$.

The Bombieri-Lang conjecture asserts that there is a proper Zariski-closed set $Z$ in $X$ such that for any finite extension $K|k$, the open set $X\backslash Z$ has only finitely many $K$-rational points.

Assume that there is a  closed set $Z \subset X$ such that the open $U:=X\backslash Z$ is proved to have a finite number of $k$-rational points. 
In this situation, what one can say about the Bombieri-Lang conjecture? is it true in this case?

Comment: Not automatically; at any rate not with the same $Z$, because there could easily be a local obstruction over $k$ that disappears over $K$.  For example, the smooth sextic surface $w^6+x^6+y^6+z^6=0$ in ${\bf P}^3$ is of general type, and has no rational points over $\bf Q$, but does have infinitely many rational points over certain number fields $K$, such as those containing $12$th roots of unity.

Comment: Lang makes a much more precise conjecture: the Zariski closure $Z$ in $X$ of the union of all images of nonconstant morphisms from rational curves and Abelian varieties defined over $\overline{k}$ should be a proper subset of $X$, and $X\setminus Z$ has only finitely many $K$-rational points for every finite $K/k$.  In your set $Z$, if $Z$ does not contain the image of every such morphism, of course $U(K)$ may be infinite even through $U(k)$ is empty.  Already for a Brauer-Severi $X$, $X(k)$ can be empty yet $X(K)$ can be infinite.

Comment: The OP specified that $X$ is of general type, so I couldn't use the counterexample of a pointless plane conic (the simplest kind of Brauer-Severi variety) or for that matter a pointless smooth quadric of arbitrary dimension.

Comment: Indeed, in my example, the X is a complete intersection of $n-2$ diagonal quadratic in the projective space ${\mathbb P}^n({\bar k})$ and it is proved that the all images of nonconstant morphisms from rational curves and Abelian varieties defined over ${\bar k}$ is the union of a finite number of lines.